# How to work around the lack of InitOnceExecuteOnce in mingw (or mingw-w64) gcc?

Tags: c, winapi, mingw, opencl

I'm trying to build the [OpenCL ICD Loader](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-ICD-Loader) in mingw gcc - no problem to use mingw-w64 instead, it's just that mingw is what I have installed already. I don't use Visual Studio - I don't hate it, I know there's free versions, it's just not what I'm using.

The OpenCL ICD Loader doesn't build in mingw gcc. The main reason is because of lack of DirectX 10 and DirectX 11 support. But all the ICD Loader does is get a dispatch table (presumably from the OpenCL driver/whatever it loads) and provide functions that call through that dispatch table. Some minor changes to the conditional compilation in `icd_dispatch.h` and `icd_dispatch.c` can omit the relevant functions and remove the dependency (as already has to happen for Linux builds), and it actually looks like this may have been supported in the past - there's preprocessor symbols `cl_khr_d3d10_sharing` and `cl_khr_d3d11_sharing` already defined if relevant headers are included, they're just not being used to conditionally compile the relevant chunks of code.

So there's that and telling the code to omit DirectX10 and DirectX11 functionality in the first place (I just commented out a couple of header-file includes, though that's obviously not a real solution). But then there's one more problem...

The file `icd_windows.c` uses the Windows API function `InitOnceExecuteOnce` - [MSDN docs here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683493(v=vs.85).aspx). mingw (and I think mingw-w64) doesn't support this function - the def file for `Kernel32.dll` lists it but neither the function nor the related identifiers `INIT_ONCE`, `INIT_ONCE_STATIC_INIT` and `PINIT_ONCE` are provided by header files.

The MSDN docs IMO don't explain this very well. It can't be essential (it didn't even exist before Vista) and it has something to do with safe initialization of DLLs, presumably in a multithreading context.

Unfortunately, if I don't really understand what it does, then I can't implement a workaround for its not being there.

Clearly this Windows API isn't specific to OpenCL, so presumably this is an issue that other people have run into for other projects. So is there a standard workaround for this?

Or failing that, can someone explain what is meant particularly by "synchronous one-time initialization"? Sorry if that's a dumb question, I don't have much experience of multithreaded, I'd have thought one-time initialization is just that, irrespective of synchronous vs. asynchronous - so long as a second thread can't re-enter the initialization, you don't want to initialize again, so there's nothing to do synchronously vs. asynchronously anyway.

Or does it mean that if another thread tries to call the initialization, it will wait for the already-running initialization to complete before it fails (or possibly succeeds without re-doing the initialization)?

---

I wasn't sure the opencl tag was appropriate, decided to include it because of the context, sorry if that was wrong.

Comment: As soon as I posted the question, [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363808(v=vs.85).aspx) moved out of my blind spot. Oops. If no better answer appears, I'll add one based on that.

Comment: Why don't you just declare the API function and identifiers yourself?

Comment: @HarryJohnston - I don't know how to define the identifiers (what the types should be etc), and guessing that it might be worth submitting some changes to Khronos and/or MinGW, I'm really not sure what the legal issues are with just copying those definitions from Microsoft headers (which I don't currently have) or somewhere on MSDN (assuming they're there somewhere). It is still an option, though.

Comment: You probably can't legally copy the declarations from the headers verbatim, but equivalent declarations *should* be safe.  [(But these days, who knows?)](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2608202/java/oracle-s-surprise-win-in-java-api-case-could-make-it-harder-for-developers.html)

Comment: Here's a bit of information, what `InitOnceExecuteOnce` does, and why: [What does INIT_ONCE_CTX_RESERVED_BITS mean?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120420-00/?p=7813)

Comment: I think I succeeded in building OpenCL.dll with MinGW. You actually don't need the definition of `InitOnceExecuteOnce`, since MinGW will recognize it as an implicit function (with a `-Wimplicit-function-declaration` warning), and the linker will properly find it in kernel32.dll.

Comment: @yixuan - I wasn't speculating that MinGW GCC compilation might fail, I tried it and it failed with errors stating that those identifiers are unknown. Also, note that it's not just the function that's needed - `INIT_ONCE` is a type (a pointer, but wrapped in clutter such as a union for some reason) and `INIT_ONCE_STATIC_INIT` is the value used to initialize it (basically null), and those are used to define and initialize a variable which is passed to `InitOnceExecuteOnce` as an argument. Those identifiers aren't present anywhere in the MinGW windows API headers (I grepped to check).

Comment: @yixuan - I suspect the project was once written to compile in MinGW GCC anyway, but that support was removed. I cloned the most recent version a couple of days before posting this question. Anyway, I looked up what the definitions were in VC++2010 Express and it shouldn't be hard to add equivalent definitions to the MinGW windows API headers, I've just been busy with other things so I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem. You have to add following line at beginning of icd_windows.c, before all #includes:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600
```

This helps with missing `InitOnceExecuteOnce` declaration. I also had to modify CMakeLists.txt, replaced `SHARED` with `STATIC` in line 22 which is responsible for linking libOpenCL. I did this because linker complained about missing ld lib:

```
add_library (OpenCL STATIC ${OPENCL_ICD_LOADER_SOURCES})
```

After doing these two things I got libOpenCL.a in build subdir. Compilation continued and failed with some other error, but I ignored this. I took created lib and successfully used it to build simple OpenCL app which lists all available platforms, devices and their details.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not really in a position to check this ATM so +1, but no accept, at least not yet. It might be a while, sorry.

Comment: No problem :) BTW, I also found that I can link my app directly with OpenCL.dll installed in Windows, it was enough to add `/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/OpenCL.dll` (without `-l`) as another arg for linker.